# Upgrade SQL Server SSIS .NET Framework 4.5 to 4.8

Tags: .net, sql-server, ssis

My application currently using SSIS data packages (.NET Framework 4.5) in Visual Studio 2015, and the deployment target server version is SQL Server 2016.

I am planning to upgrade the application to .NET Framework 4.6.2 or a newer version. What do I need to do?

Any help or link in this regard highly appreciated.

Comment: What version of SSIS? you cannot change the version of .Net that the SSIS runtime utilizes, you can only upgrade the integration services itself.

Comment: .NET Framework runtimes are backwards compatible, not forwards compatible. That means you can build a program targeting .NET Framework 4.5 and execute it on any later version of the .NET Framework - provided you're not using Reflection tricks to access private members that have since been removed or renamed. But you cannot take a program that was built for .NET Framework 4.6.2, for example, and execute it on a system that only has .NET Framework 4.5 installed. If you upgrade your program to .NET Framework 4.6.2 then the server must have .NET Framework 4.6.2 or later installed to run it.

Comment: The following articles should give you some insights regarding compatibility: [Framework targeting overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/visual-studio-multi-targeting-overview); [MSBuild target framework and target platform](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-target-framework-and-target-platform); [Target frameworks in SDK-style projects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks) and [Introduction to .NET Framework Compatibility](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/introduction-to-net-framework-compatibility/).

Comment: @AlwaysLearning thanks for the detailed insights and sharing of links. Yes, first I have installed .NET framework on server and after that redeploy the package with target framework 4.8. I am deploying the packages on SQL Server 2016, it can be reason of failure?

Comment: Your question doesn't mention any failures. What problems are you encountering?